# How do I tell buildroot to include boost in the host toolchain

Tags: linux, docker, boost, cross-compiling, buildroot

I'm replacing an older cross-compile toolchain, and I can't figure out how to get buildroot to include `host/.../sysroot/usr/include/boost`  like the old toolchain had.

Context:

I'm trying to build a docker image that can be used to cross-compile software for [MiyooCFW](https://github.com/TriForceX/MiyooCFW) in GitHub Actions. Here is my [current Dockerfile](https://github.com/nfriedly/miyoo-toolchain/blob/main/Dockerfile).

The project moved from uClibc to musl libc, which is why the toolchain needs to be updated.

The older toolchain that actually works is a [.zip file on google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zp6elbB3r4Hq7G7FKXNtBZMTz0H93RiY/view?usp=sharing). I think it was probably built using `Makefile.legacy` in this [buildroot fork](https://github.com/MiyooCFW/buildroot). The newer one uses `make sdk` with the main `Makefile` there. (There is a [bit of documentation](https://github.com/TriForceX/MiyooCFW/wiki/Build-Source), but it's incomplete.)

I installed `libboost-all-dev` which puts the libraries in `/usr/include/boost/` but just having them installed is apparently not enough.

[GMenuNX](https://github.com/nfriedly/gmenunx/tree/master) is an example program I'm trying to cross-compile that depends on boost. The `steward` branch uses a docker image with the older toolchain and [compiles successfully](https://github.com/nfriedly/gmenunx/runs/5260372765?check_suite_focus=true). The `ci` branch uses my new docker image and [fails](https://github.com/nfriedly/gmenunx/runs/5261856673?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:335) with:

```
/opt/miyoo/bin/arm-linux-g++ -ggdb -DTARGET_MIYOO -DTARGET=miyoo -D__BUILDTIME__="\"2022-02-19 18:33\"" -DLOG_LEVEL=3 -I/opt/miyoo/arm-buildroot-linux-musleabi/sysroot/usr/bin/../../usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/opt/miyoo/usr/include/ -I/opt/miyoo/arm-buildroot-linux-musleabi/sysroot/usr/include/  -I/opt/miyoo/arm-buildroot-linux-musleabi/sysroot/usr/include/SDL/ -o objs/miyoo/src/selector.o -c src/selector.cpp
src/selector.cpp:34:10: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string.hpp: No such file or directory
  34 | #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
     |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile.miyoo:31: objs/miyoo/src/selector.o] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I also tried copying the boost libs over manually, but that just got me a [bunch of *different* errors](https://github.com/nfriedly/gmenunx/runs/5274905276?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:332).

Finally, if it wasn't apparent already, I am a complete noob when it comes to buildroot, cross compiling, etc. I don't even work with c++ very often. I's very possible that I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the Buildroot toolchain to include the Boost libraries, enable the Boost package in your Buildroot configuration: BR2_PACKAGE_BOOST=y. It has a number of sub-options, make sure to enable the ones that are relevant for you.

Installing Boost on your machine will have absolutely zero effect on which libraries are available in the toolchain sysroot.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized that was how it worked. Also, it took me a minute to figure out where my config was, but I eventually ran `make menuconfig`, used `/` to search it to find the boost setting, saved that, and then did a `git diff` to realize that it was saved in `.config`.

Now that I have the toolchain built correctly with boost, I'm getting the same errors compiling as when I manually copied the library into the toolchain.. Oh well, I can work on that tomorrow.

Thank you for the answer and for all the other work you do on buildroot!